# Conflict between (cmidrule , hhline) and Alternating row colors in tables

Tags: tables

For the table in the MWE shown below I need to use the options below:

- Make rows of alternating colors
- Make horizontal lines from second to fifth column
- Give a single color to the merged cells containing the text (Multiples) & (Submultiples)

I cannot get those 2 options to work at the same time.

- For alternating row colors I am using \rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!25}
- For controlling the extension of the horizontal lines I am trying to use one of the 2 commands:

  \hhline{~----}

  \cmidrule{2-5}

Both commands cause the alternating row colors to disapear. However, the (hhline) command results in an additional issue, which is the appearence of white spaces in the place of the empty of horizontal lines.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu,multirow} 
\usepackage{array} 
\newcolumntype{?}[1]{!{\vrule width #1}} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowbottomsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovetopsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{boldline} 
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!tb]
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\begin{center}
\caption{Common multiples and submultiples of SI Units}
\label{Tab:SI}
\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!25}
\begin{tabular}{?{1mm}c|c|c|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}?{1mm}}
\rowcolor{white}
\toprule[1mm]
\multicolumn{2}{?{1mm}c|}{\textbf{Multiplication factor}} &\textbf{Exponential Form} & \textbf{Multiple Prefix} & \textbf{Multiple Abbreviation / SI SYmbol} \\
\midrule[1.5pt]
 & 1 000 000 000 000 000 000 & $10^{18}$ & exa & E \\
\hhline{~----}
 & 1 000 000 000 000 000 & $10^{15}$ & peta & P \\
\hhline{~----}
 & 1 000 000 000 000 & $10^{12}$ & tera & T \\
\hhline{~----}
 & 1 000 000 000 & $10^{9}$ & giga & G \\
\hhline{~----}
 & 1 000 000 & $10^{6}$ & mega & M \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
 & 1 000 & $10^{3}$ & kilo & k \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
 & 1 00 & $10^{2}$ & hecto & h \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
\multirow{-8}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Multiples}}} & 1 0 & $10^{1}$ & deka & da \\
\midrule[1.5pt]
 & 0.1 & $10^{-1}$ & deci & d \\
\hline
 & 0.01 & $10^{-2}$ & centi & c \\
\hline
 & 0.001 & $10^{-3}$ & milli & m \\
\hline
 & 0.000 001 & $10^{-6}$ & micro & μ \\
\hline
 & 0.000 000 001 & $10^{-9}$ & nano & n \\
\hline
 & 0.000 000 000 001 & $10^{-12}$ & pico & p \\
\hline
 & 0.000 000 000 000 001 & $10^{-15}$ & femto & f \\
\hline
\multirow{-8}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{submultiples}}} & 0.000 000 000 000 000 001 & $10^{-18}$ & atto & a \\
\bottomrule[1mm]
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

For horizontal lines I would rather use `Xhline` defined in `makecell` package. They haven't problems with coloring rows as it has `hhline` rules.  Also I would remove all `\cline` since then  table (at least to my opinion) become more nice.

**Edit:**
Unfortunately any kind of `\cline` cause your problem. So far temporary solution is not to use them, and (then) ask `colortbl` package author, how to fix this bug/misfeatures.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand\ccw{\cellcolor{white}}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\newcolumntype{?}[1]{!{\vrule width #1}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{boldline}
%\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!tb]
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\caption{Common multiples and submultiples of SI Units}
\label{Tab:SI}
    \rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!10}
\begin{tabular}{?{1pt}c|c|c|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}?{1pt}}
    \Xhline{1pt}
    &   \thead{Multiplication\\ factor}   
        &   \thead{Exponential\\ Form} 
            &   \thead{Multiple\\ Prefix} 
                &   \textbf{Multiple Abbreviation / SI SYmbol} \\
    \Xhline{0.5pt}
\ccw
    & 1 000 000 000 000 000 000 & $10^{18}$ & exa & E \\
    & 1 000 000 000 000 000 & $10^{15}$ & peta & P \\
\ccw
    & 1 000 000 000 000 & $10^{12}$ & tera & T \\
    & 1 000 000 000 & $10^{9}$ & giga & G \\
\ccw
    & 1 000 000 & $10^{6}$ & mega & M \\
    & 1 000 & $10^{3}$ & kilo & k \\
\ccw
    & 1 00 & $10^{2}$ & hecto & h \\
\multirow{-8}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Multiples}}}
    & 1 0 & $10^{1}$ & deka & da \\
    \Xhline{0.5pt}
\ccw
    & 0.1 & $10^{-1}$ & deci & d \\
    & 0.01 & $10^{-2}$ & centi & c \\
\ccw
    & 0.001 & $10^{-3}$ & milli & m \\
    & 0.000 001 & $10^{-6}$ & micro & μ \\
\ccw
    & 0.000 000 001 & $10^{-9}$ & nano & n \\
    & 0.000 000 000 001 & $10^{-12}$ & pico & p \\
\ccw
& 0.000 000 000 000 001 & $10^{-15}$ & femto & f \\
\multirow{-8}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Multiples}}}
    & 0.000 000 000 000 000 001 & $10^{-18}$ & atto & a \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Zarko, but you removed the middle horizontal lines, and alternating row colors continued till the merged cells (Multiples & Submultiples)

Comment: @Silva, I said how I would make your table. Dropped `\cline`s you can return with `\Xcline{2-5}{1pt}`. See edited answer

Comment: the command Xhline causes no issues with alternating row colors, HOWEVER, THE COMMAND Xcline {2-5}{1.5pt} CAUSES A CONFLICT WITH ALTERNATING COLORS, all rows become same color

Comment: @Silva, I test my MWE also with `Xcline`. It works without any problem. In test I use recent MikTeX. If you can not obtain desired result, than you have outdated LaTeX installation. Upgrade it. I will extend answer with showing, that Xcline works.

Comment: @Silva, you are right. It seems that should live without \Xcline or \cline  or `hhline between rows. With out them your table is -- to my opinion -- look nicer.

Comment: @ Zarko, So, is it an update issue or a matter of conflict between options?

Comment: @Silva, I don't know.

Comment: I updated all the packages and still the alternating row colors issue presists

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

In `{NiceTabular}`, you merge cells both horizontally and vertically with the command `\Block`. For the rows, you give the number of *logical* rows (and not the number of physical lines as with `\multicolumn`).

With the key `hvlines`, all the rules are drawn, excepted in the blocks (constructed by `\Block`).

I have drawn the main frame, with heavy rules, by a Tikz instruction after the construction of the main array:

`\tikz \draw [thick] (1-|1) rectangle (last-|last) ;`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!tb]
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\caption{Common multiples and submultiples of SI Units}
\label{Tab:SI}
    
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\bfseries}c|c|c|c|c}[hvlines,color-inside]
\RowStyle[cell-space-limits=3pt]{\bfseries}
    &   \Block{}{Multiplication\\ factor}   
        &   \Block{}{Exponential\\ Form} 
            &   \Block{}{Multiple\\ Prefix} 
                &   \Block{}{Multiple\\ Abbreviation\\ / SI SYmbol} \\
\rowcolors{gray!10}{}[cols=2-]
\Block{8-1}{\rotate Multiples }
    & 1 000 000 000 000 000 000 & $10^{18}$ & exa & E \\
    & 1 000 000 000 000 000 & $10^{15}$ & peta & P \\
    & 1 000 000 000 000 & $10^{12}$ & tera & T \\
    & 1 000 000 000 & $10^{9}$ & giga & G \\
    & 1 000 000 & $10^{6}$ & mega & M \\
    & 1 000 & $10^{3}$ & kilo & k \\
    & 1 00 & $10^{2}$ & hecto & h \\
    & 1 0 & $10^{1}$ & deka & da \\
\Block{8-1}{\rotate Multiples}
    & 0.1 & $10^{-1}$ & deci & d \\
    & 0.01 & $10^{-2}$ & centi & c \\
    & 0.001 & $10^{-3}$ & milli & m \\
    & 0.000 001 & $10^{-6}$ & micro & \textmu \\
    & 0.000 000 001 & $10^{-9}$ & nano & n \\
    & 0.000 000 000 001 & $10^{-12}$ & pico & p \\
    & 0.000 000 000 000 001 & $10^{-15}$ & femto & f \\
    & 0.000 000 000 000 000 001 & $10^{-18}$ & atto & a \\
\CodeAfter \tikz \draw [thick] (1-|1) rectangle (last-|last) ; 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]